# Entity Framework linq optimization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple linq query:

```
var workers = context.users.Where(w => context.memberships.Any(m => m.company_id == companyID));
```

As you can see, I'm using db context in the predicate, so I'm worried that it might cause unnecessary db calls. Does EF optimize it somehow?

Of course, I could do it like that:

```
var memberships = context.memberships.Where(m => m.company_id == companyID);
var workers = context.users.Where(w => memberships.Any(m => memberships.Contains(m)));
```

But is it better?

Comment: If you want to know what happens when that query is executed, look at the translated SQL, or profile the resulting query.

Comment: If the memberships table is small and relatively immutable then you could cache it, leaving just the users part of the query.

Comment: Is there some relation between users and memberships? I'm kind of confused just looking at the queries.

Comment: @Ixonal memberships is just table with 2 PFK (user_id, company_id)

Comment: You are not using user variable (w) in any of the queries, so they do not make much sense

Comment: So it's setting up a many-to-many relationship with companies?

Comment: @Ixonal exacly ;)